# Invalid or unexpected token | discord.js / node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've at the moment a problem with my discord.js bot. I worked on a command handler in my bot, but the console give everytime the error:'Invalid or unexpected token. The token worked before I started with the command handler. But how?

```js
// Client source
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

const Enmap = require('enmap');
const fs = require('fs');

fs.readdir("./events/", (err, files) => {
  if (err) return console.error(err);
  files.forEach(file => {
    const event = require(`./events/${file}`);
    let eventName = file.split(".")[0];
    client.on(eventName, event.bind(null, client));
  });
});

client.commands = new Enmap();
​
fs.readdir("./commands/", (err, files) => {
  if (err) return console.error(err);
  files.forEach(file => {
    if (!file.endsWith(".js")) return;
    let props = require(`./commands/${file}`);
    let commandName = file.split(".")[0];
    console.log(`Attempting to load command ${commandName}`);
    client.commands.set(commandName, props);
  });
});

// Client token
client.login('NTA4NDUzNDUzMjg3MjYwMTcx.DvXXqg.knAWs-zDEkwtz6MVfFxT7GPk7Pc');
```

Comment: You have an invalid character right below `client.commands = new Enmap();` (zero-width space)

Comment: You just published your discord token.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You actually have an invalid character, but it is invisible. You have a "Zero width space [U+200B](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200b/index.htm). It is just in the blank line in middle of this part:

```
client.commands = new Enmap();
​  //<-- your invalid character is there
fs.readdir("./commands/", (err, files) => {
```

Just delete and you're good to go.

Comment: Typo questions are off-topic - they're by definition never have any use at all to anyone other than the asker, which is not what SO is for. You should vote to close typo questions instead of answering. See [Should you answer questions where the cause of the problem is a typo?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366135/should-you-answer-questions-where-the-cause-of-the-problem-is-a-typo)

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, and first of all let me say that I totally understand the point on typo questions and I agree. However, in my lecture of the question, I consider the problem more subtle, more surprising than, say, the lack of a comma or so (furthermore, I doubt OP literally "typed" it there). An invisible character isn't something you can spot by careful reading (specially a zero-width one), and I'd bet many people (even non-newbies) would be surprised by the source of the error in this case. Therefore, I believe this question can be of public interest.